# System.ArgumentException: 'Value' property was already registered by 'Point'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a class called ShellViewModel and a WPF page called Shell.xaml. In my ShellViewModel I have a function that reads data from a .csv file and displays the data into the datagrid in Shell.xaml The data is graphed on a graph as a line plot.

The file is read fine and the data is displayed correctly on the datagrid. The structure of the data has 25 columns. The first column is the name of the data and the next 24 columns are data points. Although the data is displayed properly in the datagrid, the graph has no data points in it.

This is the code for my graph. The error I'm getting is "

> **System.ArgumentException: 'Value' property was already registered by 'Point'**"

Notes: obsLoadForecasts has the data stored that gets displayed in the datagrid

Code from ShellViewModel.cs for the graph:

```
public void UpdateLoadChart()
{
    var forecastList = obsLoadForecasts.ToList();
    var dataList = new List<ForecastPoint>();

    forecastList.Where(a => a.ObsForecast.ZoneName == zoneName).ToList().ForEach(a =>
    {
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(1, a.ObsForecast.Hr1));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(2, a.ObsForecast.Hr2));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(3, a.ObsForecast.Hr3));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(4, a.ObsForecast.Hr4));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(5, a.ObsForecast.Hr5));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(6, a.ObsForecast.Hr6));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(7, a.ObsForecast.Hr7));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(8, a.ObsForecast.Hr8));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(9, a.ObsForecast.Hr9));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(10, a.ObsForecast.Hr10));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(11, a.ObsForecast.Hr11));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(12, a.ObsForecast.Hr12));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(13, a.ObsForecast.Hr13));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(14, a.ObsForecast.Hr14));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(15, a.ObsForecast.Hr15));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(16, a.ObsForecast.Hr16));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(17, a.ObsForecast.Hr17));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(18, a.ObsForecast.Hr18));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(19, a.ObsForecast.Hr19));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(20, a.ObsForecast.Hr20));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(21, a.ObsForecast.Hr21));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(22, a.ObsForecast.Hr22));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(23, a.ObsForecast.Hr23));
        dataList.Add(new ForecastPoint(24, a.ObsForecast.Hr24));
    });

    ObsLoadChartData = dataList;
    RaisePropertyChanged("ObsLoadChartData");

    if (!(obsLoadForecasts.Exists(a => a.ObsForecast.ZoneName.Contains("Interchange"))))
    {
        try
        {
            //Peak Load Forecast values defined
            maxRTOvalue = dataList.Max(ForecastPoint => ForecastPoint.Value);
            maxRTOhour = dataList.FindIndex(ForecastPoint => ForecastPoint.Value == maxRTOvalue);
            maxRTOhour = maxRTOhour + 1;
        }
        catch
        {
            Log("Unable to determine Peak Load Forecast ");

            maxRTOvalue = 0;
            maxRTOhour = 0;
            maxRTOhour = 0;
        }
    }
}

public class ForecastPoint : DependencyObject
{
    public ForecastPoint(int hour, decimal value)
    {
        Hour = hour;
        Value = value;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty _hour = DependencyProperty.Register("Hour", typeof(Int32), typeof(ForecastPoint));
    public Int32 Hour
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(_hour); }
        set { SetValue(_hour, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty _value = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(decimal), typeof(Point));
    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return (decimal)GetValue(_value); }
        set { SetValue(_value, value); }
    }
}
```

Code in Shell.xaml:

```
<me:LoadChart x:Name="MyLoadChart" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
```

Code in my LoadChart.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProbeCTO.LoadChart"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         xmlns:chartingPrimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         xmlns:datavis="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         xmlns:me="clr-namespace:ProbeCTO"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type charting:Chart}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type charting:Chart}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20 0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultButtonBrush}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />

                            <!-- Use a nested Grid to avoid possible clipping behavior resulting from ColumnSpan+Width=Auto -->
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,15,0,15">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <chartingPrimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                                    <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                                    <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1 0 0 1" />
                                </chartingPrimitives:EdgePanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <charting:Chart x:Name="MyChart" Title="{Binding ObsSelectedLoadForecast.ObsForecast.ZoneName, TargetNullValue=RTO, FallbackValue=RTO}" Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Foreground="#DDD" BorderThickness="0">
        <charting:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Style>
        </charting:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
        <charting:Chart.Axes>
            <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="False" Interval="1" />
            <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="False" />
        </charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:Chart.Series>
            <charting:AreaSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ObsLoadChartData}"
                                         IndependentValuePath="Hour"
                                         DependentValuePath="Value">
            </charting:AreaSeries>
            <charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ObsLoadChartData}"
                                         IndependentValuePath="Hour"
                                         DependentValuePath="Value">
            </charting:LineSeries>
        </charting:Chart.Series>
    </charting:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: You passed a wrong argument to `DependencyProperty.Register`. I do that twice a week thanks to copy and paste.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty _value = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", 
        typeof(decimal), 
        typeof(ForecastPoint));
```

The last argument was `typeof(Point)` in your snippet, but it needs to be `typeof(ForecastPoint)` -- the type of the declaring class, as it is a few lines above there where you register the `Hour` property.

By the way, I would name those `ValueProperty` and `HourProperty` instead of `_value` and `_hour`. That's the convention, and it's what people expect to see. Anybody trying to call `obj.SetValue(ForecastPoint.ValueProperty, value)` will be in for some minor unnecessary frustration.

Comment: @someone If this answer fixed your problem, you should mark it as the correct answer.